# Remove 1 element from Embed object DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to code a bot that copies 1 embed from 1 channel to another channel.

But what I want it to do before posting it to the other channel, I want it to remove 1 element from the embed object.

How I have it currently:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id == channel1) {
        const embed = message.embeds[0];
    
        var params = {
            embeds: [embed],
        };
    
        fetch("WEBHOOK URL", {
            //send channel 2
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params),
        }).then((res) => {});
    }
});
```

As you can see i straight use message.embeds[0].

So i don't even know if it possible to remove 1 element from it like the footer text for example.

If anyone knows if it can be done or not, please say so.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT:

Would it be something like:

```js
const embed = message.embeds[0];

embed.footer.text = [];
// or
embed.footer[0].text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to remove a property from an object.

```js
const embed = message.embeds[0];
if (!embed) return;

delete embed.footer;

message.channel.send({
    content: "Footer removed!",
    embeds: [embed]
});
```

Note that you can't remove only the `text` property and keep the icon. The footer won't show without a `text` property.

[image]

These work too:

```js
// Remove only text from footer (footer won't be visible including icon)
embed.footer.text = "";
// Or
embed.footer = {};
// Or
embed.footer = null;
// Or ...
```

Comment: 1 question, What if i am doing this for multiple messages, and 1 embed doesnt have footer? Can i detect like if(embed.footer) so it doesn't crash my bot?

Comment: Yep, it would be nice to use that check if you are accessing a property of the `footer`, for example `.text`. If you are just doing `delete embed.footer`, there is no need for such check, the property footer is always there (on the embed object), it is just `null` if there is no actual footer.

Comment: Also if you are trying to delete an object's property that does not exist, the `delete` operator returns `true` and proceeds with no error. As stated in the MDN docs (linked in my answer).